# github actions pnpm build error ts2322 , But it's normal locally

Tags: typescript, dependencies, github-actions, cicd, tsc

github actions pnpm build error ts2322 , But it's normal locally

error info:
Error:  ../../packages/hooks/use-forward-ref/index.ts:20:5 - error TS2322: Type '(el: T) => void' is not assignable to type 'ForwardRefSetter'.
Types of parameters 'el' and 'el' are incompatible.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.

20     setForwardRef,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~

https://github.com/lixiaofa/fast-plus/actions/runs/5532747753/jobs/10107559848

pnpm build that is  normal
no error